# Is there a CUDA threadId alike in Jax (google)?

Tags: jax

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of `jax.vmap/pmap`, (jax: https://jax.readthedocs.io/). CUDA has threadId to let you know which thread is executing the code, is there a similar concept in jax? (`jax.process_id` is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no real analog to CUDA threadid in JAX. Details about GPU thread assignment are handled at a lower level by the XLA compiler, and I don't know of any straightforward API to plumb this information back to JAX's Python runtime.

One case where JAX does offer higher-level handling of device assignment is when using `pmap`; in this case you can explicitly pass a set of device IDs to the pmapped function if you want logic that depends on the device on which the mapped code is being executed. For example, I ran the following on an 8-device system:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

num_devices = jax.device_count()

def f(device, data):
  return data + device

device_index = jnp.arange(num_devices)
data = jnp.zeros((num_devices, 10))

jax.pmap(f)(device_index, data)

# ShardedDeviceArray([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#                     [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#                     [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
#                     [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
#                     [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
#                     [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
#                     [6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
#                     [7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7.]], dtype=float32)
```